# Title for colorbar in Plotly Heatmap

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

This is my code:

```
fig = go.Figure(
    data=go.Heatmap(z=z_values, y=[str(x) for x in params_1], x=[str(x) for x in params_2]), 
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Analysis results",
        xaxis=dict(title='Diameter'),
        yaxis=dict(title='Max Distance')
    ),
)
fig.show()
```

It generates a 2D-heatmap (snippet below), but I'd like to include a title for the colorbar:

[image]

Unfortunately the plotly [example](https://plot.ly/python/colorscales/) also does not have a colorbar title.
I have tried to include the colorbar properties with the "marker" but this throws an error.
How can I do that hence?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
fig = go.Figure(
    data=go.Heatmap(z=z_values, y=[str(x) for x in params_1], x=[str(x) for x in params_2]), 
colorbar=dict(title='Title') , 
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Analysis results",
        xaxis=dict(title='Diameter'),
        yaxis=dict(title='Max Distance')
    ),
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I get this then: File "<ipython-input-29-d28f3554fbb7>", line 19
    colorbar=dict(title=‘Title’)
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: Then changed ‘Title’ to  'Test' (different hyphens) but got: ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Layout: 'colorbar'

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 15):

Just include `colorbar={"title": 'Your title'}` in `go.Heatmap()` to get this:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(colorbar={"title": "Your title"},
                                            z=[[1, 20, 30],
                                              [20, 1, 60],
                                              [30, 60, 1]]))
 fig.show()
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also do it after by updating the layout:

```
fig.update_layout(
    coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
        title="Your Title",
    ),
)
```

Comment: did NOT work for me...    plotly==5.9.0

Comment: @Julian-BrainAnnex.org -- I had a similar issue, but found that this works if you specify the coloraxis the heatmap should use. E.g. 
```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(x=..., y=..., z=..., coloraxis='coloraxis'))
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_title='Your Title')
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
fig = ...
fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title = 'Title<br>Here'
```

Comment: This one is universal and works with px.imshow as well. You can edit the title more using standard plotly arguments here as well: `{'text':'Title', 'font':{'size':30}}`

Comment: This works with all plotly express plots as well. Very helpful!

Comment: did NOT work for me... plotly==5.9.0

Comment: @Julian-BrainAnnex.org -- I had a similar issue, but found that this works if you specify the coloraxis the heatmap should use. E.g. 
```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(x=..., y=..., z=..., coloraxis='coloraxis'))
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_title='Your Title')
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these were working for me but doing this updated it without any issue:

```
fig = ...
fig.data[0].colorbar.title = "Title Here"
```

Comment: Works perfectly in plotly==5.9.0     


If you do a `print(fig)`  , you can see that the Figure object now contains `'data': [{'colorbar': {'title': {'text': 'Title Here'}},` etc    


Note that with this approach, we're back to adding the colorbar title in the *data* section, just as done in the chosen answer